# function recursion in clojure

Tags: recursion, clojure

Im dealing with recursion in clojure, which i dont really understand.
I made a small program taked from [here](https://projecteuler.net/problem=5) that tries to find the smalles number that can be divided by all the numbers from 1 to 20. This is the code i wrotte, but there must be something im missing because it does not work.
Could you give me a hand? thanks!

```
(defn smallest [nume index]
(while(not ( = index 0))
    (do
        (cond
            (zero?(mod nume index))(let [dec' index] (smallest nume index))
            :else (let [inc' nume] (smallest nume index))))))
```

EDIT: 
Looks like is better `loop/recur` so i tried it:

```
(loop [nume 20
            index 20]
        (if (= index 0)
        (println nume)
        (if (zero?(mod nume index))
                (recur nume (dec index))
                (recur (inc nume) 20)))))
```

Working. If you are curious about result--> 232792560

Comment: Invest in understanding loop/recur, immutability and the standard libraries sequence transformation functions - `while` is an imperative looping construct which in my experience one never uses more than once or twice a year.

Comment: It seem you are shooting in the dark.. For instance, what do you think `(index 20)` does? Also, in `recur`, the order of the values matters, I am not sure you are doing what you think you are.

Comment: I just edited the problem about order. What i mean with `(index 20)` is to set index to 20 again. @shlomi

Comment: @Capie, so that is not what this is doing. In fact, it will throw an error, because `index` is not a function, and you are attempting to apply 20 to the function `index`. If you want to keep `index` as 20, you should simply do `(recur (inc nume) 20)`. This comment also applies to `(nume)`, you are trying to invoke the number :). I updated my answer, see if that helps a little more.

Comment: @shlomi Helped a lot. It´s working. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`while`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/loop) does not do what you think it does.

In clojure, everything (well, almost) is immutable, meaning that if `index` is 0, it will always be 0 in the same context. Thus looping until it is 1 makes little sense.

There are a number of ways to achieve what you are trying to do, the first, and most trivial (I think!) to newcomers, is to understand [`loop/recur`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/loop). So for example:

```
(loop [counter 0] 
  (when (< counter 10) 
    (println counter)
    (recur (inc counter))))
```

In here, `counter` is defined to be 0, and it never changes in the usual way. When you hit `recur`, you submit a new value, in this case the increment of the previous `counter`, into a brand new iteration starting at `loop`, only now `counter` will be bound to 1.

**Edit:** Notice however, that this example will always return `nil`. It is only used for the side effect of `println`. Why does it return `nil`? Because in the last iteration, the `when` clause will return `nil`. If you want to return something else, you should perhaps use `if` and specify what would you like to be returned at the last iteration.

You should read a little more about this paradigm, and perhaps do exercises like [4clojure](https://www.4clojure.com/) to get a better grasp at this. Once you do, it will become MUCH simpler for you to think in this way, and the tremendous benefits of this style will begin to emerge.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a brute force implementation testing all numbers on the condition if they can be divided by all numbers from 1 to 10 (please note (range 1 11)) in the code:

```
(first 
  (filter #(second %) 
          (map (fn[x] [x (every? identity 
                                  (map #(=  0 (mod x %)) 
                                  (range 2 11)))]) 
               (range 1 Integer/MAX_VALUE))))
```

It's output is

```
[2520 true]
```

Unfortunately, this is not a good approach for bigger numbers. With (range 1 21) it doesn't finish after few minutes of waiting on my Macbook. Let's try this:

```
user=> (defn gcd [a b] (if (zero? b) a (recur b (mod a b))))
#'user/gcd
user=> (reduce (fn[acc n] (if (not= 0 (mod acc n)) (* acc (/ n (gcd n acc))) acc)) 1 (range 1 11))
2520    
user=> (reduce (fn[acc n] (if (not= 0 (mod acc n)) (* acc (/ n (gcd n acc))) acc)) 1 (range 1 21))
232792560
```

Comment: `#(second %)` is identical to simply `second` :)